# Should Jews read the 4 parshiyot in private if they can’t join a minyan

Tags: halacha, minyan, orach-chaim, petur-exemption, four-parshiot

In Halacha, if Jews can’t go to a minyan in person, are they  obligated to read  4 parshiyot in private even without a public Torah reading? Or is the obligation to hear them only if you can in a formal Torah reading with a minyan?

Comment: [Halachipedia's "Four Parshiot"](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Four_Parshiot#Parshat_Zachor) cites [Rama in SA OC 685:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.685.7?lang=bi&lang2=en), to say: "If one can’t make it to hear Parshat Zachor in a minyan one should read it with the Trup from a Sefer." The same seems true for Parshat Parah, as both are said (by some) to be biblically cammanded. It seems not to be so for the other 2 parshiyot.